# How do I write my NodeJS server to an existing domain?

Tags: node.js, webserver, filezilla

Okay so I'm in like a really weird spot.

I need to set up a nodejs server for a messaging app, and I want to put the server on a url I already have. I have full access my directory on that site (ex. I can access sitename.com/~mypage/) and do things with it through filezilla, but I cannot access the hardware or the base domain (ex. I can't touch sitename.com but I can access ~mypage).

how would I set up the server on there? Do I need to initialize it on my own computer then upload it or do I install nodejs on the server and initialize it there? or can I use a local host for the app? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

if you already have a site running you won't be able to just slot a node app into ~mypage by adding it through filezilla.

The best way to do this in my opinion is by setting up through your domain management that ~mypage points to where you have deployed your node app (ie heroku, AWS), but if you have access to do that you may as well set up a subdomain to route to the app (ie app.sitename.com)

However, if you really cant access the domain settings, my suggestion would be to deploy your node app on Heroku, AWS or GCP then either:

A) set up a a ~mypage that redirects you to your app url if someone visits it
OR
B) set up a page with masked forwarding like so (so the browser url stays as sitename.com/~mypage/):

```
<html>  
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <META name="description" content="Page Description"><META name="keywords" content="keywords, for, page">
</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://linktoyourapp.herokuapp.com" frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>
</html>
```